# Digits Regular Expression Validator

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex

i need a regular expression validation for

```
numeric digits grouped as X-XXXXX-XXX-X
```

can any one help?

Comment: For every X you replace it with [0-9] and you're done?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Regex reg =  new Regex("\b[0-9]\-[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]\b");
```

Answer (score 1):

`(^\d{1}-\d{5}-\d{3}-\d{1}$)`, this should do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I use for checking social security numbers that user's input:

```
Public Shared Function CheckSSNFormat(ByVal text As String) As Boolean
    Dim digits As String = Regex.Replace(text, "[^0-9]", "")
    Return digits.Length = 9
End Function
```

It doesn't check that they are input in a specific format, but that might be better depending on what you really need -- so just thought I'd give you another option, just incase.

The above just removes everything except digits, and returns true if there are 9 digits (a valid SS#).  It does mean some goofy user could enter something like: hello123456789 and it would accept it as valid, but that is fine for me, and I'd rather do that than not accept 123456789 just because I was looking for 123-45-6789 only.

Later I use this to save to my database:

```
Public Shared Function FormatSSNForSaving(ByVal text As String) As String
    If text = "" Then text = "000-00-0000"
    Return Regex.Replace(text, "[^0-9]", "")
End Function
```

and this anytime I want to display the value (actually I use this one for phone numbers, turns out I never display the SS# so don't have a function for it):

```
Public Shared Function FormatPhoneForDisplay(ByVal text As String) As String
    If text.Length <> 10 Then Return text
    Return "(" & text.Substring(0, 3) & ") " & text.Substring(3, 3) & "-" & text.Substring(6, 4)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]
```

you could also use round brackets to extract the numbers if you want:

```
([0-9])-([0-9]{5})-([0-9]{3})-([0-9])
```

and get the values with $1 $2 etc. in the Regex.Replace() function

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex pattern = new Regex("\b\d-\d{5}-\d{3}-\d\b");

\b - word boundary
\d - digit
```